# Trouble importing a csv file from gcloud bucket into a table within gcloud sql database

Tags: postgresql, import, copy, gcloud

I am trying to import a CSV file from gcloud bucket into a table within gcloud postgres sql database. I have tried two different methods to do this. Hitting roadblocks in either of the methods described below:

I created the tables from a Jupyter notebook, using sqalchemy and psycopg connection.

1. I am using the import button provided in the gcloud instance. Getting this:

```
Import failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "customer_id"
CONTEXT: COPY books, line 1, column customer_id: "customer_id
```

2. When I move the file onto the SQL VM instance, I am able to use SQL copy query to upload the data. However, I am unable to do this anymore - as cloud says i am out of storage, despite using only 2.5 GB of my 200 GB.

can you please help me fix the above errors

Comment: It's hard to know the reason for you running OOM in the instance without the logs or the error message. Can you share those with me?

Answer (score 0):

You should post separate questions separately.

For your first one, it appears that the file has a header line, but you didn't tell COPY this fact.  So it is trying to use the header "customer_id" as if it were an integer.  Add the HEADER option.